# Sample Project for using webcam as camera in android emulator

Tags: android, sdk, camera, emulation, webcam

I've started developing for Android.
I want to write an barcode scanning app, but without a way to activate the camera in the emulator it could be annoying.

Does anybody knows a way to use the USB-Webcam of my PC as an Android Camera ?
I've searched everywhere i know there is a lib from tomgibara, but it would be really nice if some has got an sample project for this.

At the moment the Emulator only asks for the capturing device, but when i start now the camera app from android i only see this dummy camera site with this chessy squares.

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which camera to use and how in the `emulator` command line using the options

```
-fake-camera <mode>                   set fake camera emulation mode
```

where mode can be one of `back`, `front`, or `off`, and

```
-webcam name=<name>[,dir=<direction>] setup web camera emulation
```

where name is a valid connected camera name and dir is one of `front` or `back`.
The connected camera names can be obtained by using the special option `-webcam list`.
For example, in Linux you can obtain something like

```
List of web cameras connected to the computer:
 Camera 'webcam0' is connected to device '/dev/video0' on channel 0 using pixel format 'YUYV'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK after some tries I am able to run the emulator on the way you described above, but the fake-camera option does not help =( 
It let me choose which camera I want use and after i clicked "OK" the emulator starts, but without the webcam as front or back camera =(
Is it possible that it is a webcam which is not supported ?
 If Yes: which cameras are supported ?